# Vector not getting inserted

Tags: c++, vector

I have two class which is Player and Deck. Both Player and Deck has a vector of Card type. I'm trying to draw card from deck, which then remove the card in the deck card vector and then adding it into the player card vector. However, the card in deck is removed successfully but the card in my player is not being added. The vector size of cards in Player remain 0.

Code:

(Deck)

```
void Deck::GiveCards(std::vector<Player> pv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for each(Player p in pv) {
            int a = rand() % Deck::deckCards.size();
            CardType card = Deck::deckCards[a];
            p.DrawCard(card, p.GetHands());
            Deck::deckCards.erase(Deck::deckCards.begin()+a);
        }
    }
}
```

(Player)

```
void Player::DrawCard(CardType card, std::vector<CardType>& hand) {
    hand.push_back(card);
}

std::vector<CardType> Player::GetHands() {
    return Player::handCards;
}
```

I'm sure that the code in Deck is working perfectly. It execute the entire code in Deck. But, for some reason, it's not pushing the value into the vector in Player class.

Full code:

(Deck)

```
Deck::Deck() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // i refer to color
        CardType card(EnumValue::ZERO, EnumValue::NONE, i);
        Deck::InsertCardToDeck(card);
        for (int j = 1; j <= 18; j++) {
            int cardValue = ceil(j / 2.0);
            CardType card(cardValue, EnumValue::NONE, i);
            Deck::InsertCardToDeck(card);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (j < 2) {
                CardType card(EnumValue::SKIP, EnumValue::SKIP_EFFECT, i);
                Deck::InsertCardToDeck(card);
            }
            else if (j < 4) {
                CardType card(EnumValue::REVERSE, EnumValue::REVERSE_EFFECT, i);
                Deck::InsertCardToDeck(card);
            }
            else {
                CardType card(EnumValue::DRAW2, EnumValue::DRAW2_EFFECT, i);
                Deck::InsertCardToDeck(card);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        CardType card(EnumValue::DRAW4, EnumValue::DRAW4_EFFECT, EnumValue::RAINBOW);
        Deck::InsertCardToDeck(card);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        CardType card(EnumValue::WILD, EnumValue::WILD_EFFECT, EnumValue::RAINBOW);
        Deck::InsertCardToDeck(card);
    }
}

void Deck::InsertCardToDeck(CardType card) {
    Deck:deckCards.insert(deckCards.end(), card);
}

std::string Deck::PrintDeck() {
    std::string textOutput = "";
    std::vector<int>::size_type sz = Deck::deckCards.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        textOutput += std::string("Card ") + std::to_string(i) + ": It's a " + GetColorValue(deckCards[i].GetColor()) + " " + GetNumberValue(deckCards[i].GetValue()) + "\r\n";
    }
    return textOutput;
}

std::string Deck::GetColorValue(int color) {
    switch (color) {
    case 0:
        return "RED";
    case 1:
        return "YELLOW";
    case 2:
        return "GREEN";
    case 3:
        return "BLUE";
    default:
        return "RAINBOW";
    }
}

std::string Deck::GetNumberValue(int color) {
    switch (color) {
    case 0:
        return "ZERO";
    case 1:
        return "ONE";
    case 2:
        return "TWO";
    case 3:
        return "THREE";
    case 4:
        return "FOUR";
    case 5:
        return "FIVE";
    case 6:
        return "SIX";
    case 7:
        return "SEVEN";
    case 8:
        return "EIGHT";
    case 9:
        return "NINE";
    case 10:
        return "SKIP";
    case 11:
        return "REVERSE";
    case 12:
        return "DRAW 2";
    case 13:
        return "DRAW 4";
    default:
        return "WILD";
    }
}

void Deck::ShuffleDeck() {
    std::random_shuffle(Deck::deckCards.begin(), Deck::deckCards.end());
}

void Deck::GiveCards(std::vector<Player>& pv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for(Player p:pv) {
            int a = rand() % Deck::deckCards.size();
            CardType card = Deck::deckCards[a];
            p.DrawCard(card, p.GetHands());
            Deck::deckCards.erase(Deck::deckCards.begin()+a);
        }
    }
}
```

(Player)

```
void Player::DrawCard(CardType card, std::vector<CardType>& hand) {
    hand.push_back(card);
}

std::vector<CardType>& Player::GetHands() {
    return handCards;
}

Player::Player() {
    int a = rand() % 10;
    Player::name = "Bot Player " + std::to_string(a);
}

Player::Player(std::string names) {
    Player::name = names;
}

std::string Player::PrintCard() {
    std::string c = Player::name;
    for(CardType a:handCards) {
        c += std::string(" has: ") + Deck::GetColorValue(a.GetColor()) + " " + Deck::GetNumberValue(a.GetValue()) + "\r\n";
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: You take `pv` by copy instead of by reference. So when the players' `DrawCard()` function is called, it's only copies of the players, not the original players that are modified.

Comment: This isn't valid C++ unless you have some odd macros.

Comment: jogojapan: void DeckType::GiveCards(std::vector<Player>& pv) ?

chris: I'm new to C++.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's equivalent to the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959694/why-does-call-by-value-example-not-modify-input-parameter

Comment: Even after I modify to parse value by reference, the vector remain empty.

Comment: @Ophitect, I don't see how being new to C++ is relevant. This shouldn't compile without obscure macros, yet you describe runtime behaviour.

Comment: @chris, to be honest; I don't even know what you mean by obscure macros?

Comment: @Ophitect, Good, but I'd like to know how you got `for each(Player p in pv) {` to compile.

Comment: @Ophitect: `Player::GetHands()` is returning a `vector` by value instead of by reference, so it is returning a copy. You are passing that copy to `DrawCard()`, thus you are still not modifying the player's original hand directly.

Comment: @chris Why wouldn't it compile? I don't understand. I always do that in C# or Java.

Comment: @chris: That is actually a [Microsoft syntax from C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx) that they also allow in C++. They even recommend not using it.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, Hmm, thanks. You'd think they'd just stick with C#'s `foreach (... in ...)` I'm willing to bet its use wasn't discouraged until C++11 came.

Comment: @chris: Yeah, the "this is for chumps, do not use" recommendation is new with the VS2013 version of that documentation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, Interesting, but didn't 2010 have range-based for loops?

Comment: @chris: I just checked MSDN and it looks like range-based `for` is VS2012 and above.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I must be tired.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll start to use range-based for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function,

```
std::vector<CardType> Player::GetHands() {
    return Player::handCards;
}
```

you are returning a copy of `Player::handCard`. Change it to return a reference instead:

```
std::vector<CardType>& Player::GetHands() {
    return handCards;
}
```

**Update**

Change

```
    for each(Player p in pv) {
```

to

```
    for each(Player& p in pv) {
```

**Update 2**

In response to the latest comment from @Ophitect.

Looks like

```
   for each(Player p in pv) {
```

cannot be used get a non-const reference to the objects in `pv`. I would change that loop to:

```
    std::vector<Player>::iterator iter = pv.begin();
    std::vector<Player>::iterator end = pv.end();
    for (; iter != end; ++iter ) {
        Player& p = *iter;
        int a = rand() % Deck::deckCards.size();
        CardType card = Deck::deckCards[a];
        p.DrawCard(card, p.GetHands());
        Deck::deckCards.erase(Deck::deckCards.begin()+a);
    }
```

Comment: Modified to return a reference but still can't seems to push back the value into the vector.

Comment: @Ophitect, you have a line `for each(Player p in pv) {`. That is not C++ code. Can you post the code you are using? You may have another case of using a copy and not a reference problem.

Comment: It's valid in Visual C++.  Assuming the version of Visual C++ being used supports it a range based loop would be better, and portable.

Comment: Error 28 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const Player' to 'Player &'

Comment: Yes. It worked. C++ is so much more difficult that I expected. So I would also need to use reference in a loop?

Comment: @Ophitect C++ has much steeper learning curve than many other languages. However, there is a reason for the way it is. I hope you stick to it for a while and learn to use its power. Yes, you have to use a reference in the loop. Otherwise, you'll be modifying local copies of the objects in `pv`.

Comment: Yea. I guess I'll have to stick to it for a while since I'm learning it. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
void Deck::GiveCards(std::vector<Player> &pv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for each(Player& p in pv) {
            int a = rand() % deckCards.size();
            p.GiveCard(deckCards[a]);
            deckCards.erase(deckCards.begin()+a);
        }
    }
}

void Player::GiveCard(const CardType& card) {
    handCards.push_back(card);
}
```

Or this:

```
void Deck::GiveCards(std::vector<Player> &pv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for each(Player& p in pv) {
            p.DrawRandomCard(*this);
        }
    }
}

CardType Deck::DrawRandomCard()
{
    int a = rand() % deckCards.size();
    CardType card = deckCards[a];
    deckCards.erase(deckCards.begin()+a);
    return card;
}

void Player::DrawRandomCard(Deck& deck) {
    handCards.push_back(deck.DrawRandomCard());
}
```