# How to understanding pointers in functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-value

I have two files, `main.c` and `main2.c`. My experience tells me that they should do exactly the same, but they do not.

`main.c` declares a global variable outside the `main` routine. Then, inside the `main` routine, a pointer is declared and defined to point to that global variable. The global variable is changed, and the value of the local variable is printed to screen.

`main2.c` does the same, but convolutes local-to-global definition and change of global variable value into another function, `change_number`.

I cannot understand why this approach fails. `main.c` and `main2.c` are the boiled down results from a few hours of bugs fixing, documentation and tutorial reading and, obviously, reading here on SO.

My understanding of pointers is what I would call rudimentary: It points to a memory location. In case of a regular variable, the pointer would point to the memory location of that variable. Several pointers can point to the same memory location, but one pointer cannot point to several locations.

There's no such thing as pass-by-reference in C, but, as far as I know, this is not pass by reference since all variable and pointers are defined outside the function. Please enlighten me.

```
//File: main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int global_number;

int main() {
    int *local_number;
    local_number = &global_number;
    global_number = 9;
    printf("local_number = %d\n", *local_number);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: "local_number = 9". This is the expected result.

```
//File: main2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int global_number;

void change_number(int *number) {
    number = &global_number;
    global_number = 9;
}

int main() {
    int *local_number;
    change_number(local_number);
    printf("local_number = %d\n", *local_number);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: "Segmentation fault". This is obviously not intended. The code runs fine right up until printf().

Comment: C uses pass-by-value. `number` inside `change_number` is a different variable to `local_number` in main.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable changed in function not seen by caller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320240/variable-changed-in-function-not-seen-by-caller)

Comment: this line: number = &global_number; should be: *number = &global_number  I.E. number is a pointer to local_number.  the code needs to set the value where the number pointer is pointing

Comment: yes it is a duplicate, but the pointers and dereferences obscure it

Comment: @user3629249, no, that would assign a pointer to an integer

Comment: Matt, I can't see how this is a duplicate. The referenced question is not why pointer referencing doesn't work, but rather a programmer finding out why pointers make sense. It could be the same problems we've run in to, I just can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you never initialize `local_number` in the second program.  It does not point anywhere, and will crash when accessed.  Try

```
int *local_number = &global_number;
```

then the value should change

To have change_number also initialize local_number, pass the *address* of local_number and change the *pointed-to pointer*:

```
void change_number( int **number ) {
    *number = &global_number;
    global_number = 9;
}

...
int *local_number;
change_number(&local_number);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make the code work. I guess I expected that since the pointer was declared and I passed the pointer I could define it in the function.