# Global variables to local variables

Tags: c, algorithm, computer-science

My program to find the roots of a function using the quadratic formula is below. It works perfectly. However I was unable to get it to work without defining three of the variables globally; which, according to my project description, I am not supposed to do.

Any suggestions or alterations on how to define them locally and have the calculations not get lost before the print results function is able to do so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double discriminant;
double root_one = 0, root_two = 0;
double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

int checkComplex(double a, double b, double c)
{
    discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * (a * c);

    if (discriminant == 0)
        return 2;

    else if (discriminant > 0)
        return 1;

    else
        return 0;
}// end checkComplex

void calculateRoots(double a, double b, double c)
{
    root_one = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    root_two = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
} // end calculateRoots

void getData()
{
    printf("Enter a: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);

    printf("\nEnter b: ");
    scanf("%lf", &b);

    printf("\nEnter c: ");
    scanf("%lf", &c);
}// end getData

void printResults()
{
    if (checkComplex(a, b, c) == 1)
    {
        calculateRoots(a, b, c);
        printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nThe quantity (b^2-4ac) is %.2lf", discriminant);
        printf("\n\nfirst root = %.2lf\nsecond root = %.2lf\n\n", root_one,
               root_two);
    }// if discriminant is 1


    else if (checkComplex(a, b, c) == 0)
    {
        printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("The discriminant (b^2-4ac) is negative (imaginary)");
        printf("\nTherefore, the roots are complex\n");
    } // if discriminant is 0

    else if (checkComplex(a == 2, b == 2, c == 2))
    {
        calculateRoots(a, b, c);
        printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nThe quantity (b^2-4ac) is %.2lf", discriminant);
        printf("\n\nfirst root = %.2lf\nsecond root = %.2lf\n\n", root_one,
               root_two);
    }// if discriminant is greater than 1
} // end printResults

int main()
{
    getData();
    printResults();
    return 0;
} // End program
```

Comment: Define them in main then pass by reference instead of by value.

Comment: `checkComplex(a == 2, b == 2, c == 2)`.... huh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable changed in function not seen by caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320240/variable-changed-in-function-not-seen-by-caller)

Comment: Note that you should check that the inputs were correct (that the `scanf()` functions all read a value), and handle failures appropriately.

Comment: If you need to handle complex roots, why not use complex arithmetic, and print simple real values if in fact you have simple roots?  Using the `complex` data type cuts out a lot of the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return multiple values, you can return a struct, or you can accept pointers to where the result should be stored. I've used both approaches in the following solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
   double discriminant;
   char num_roots;
   double roots[2];
} roots_t;

void getData(double* ap, double* bp, double* cp) {
   printf("Enter a: ");   scanf("%lf", ap);
   printf("Enter b: ");   scanf("%lf", bp);
   printf("Enter c: ");   scanf("%lf", cp);
}

roots_t calculateRoots(double a, double b, double c) {
   roots_t roots;
   roots.discriminant = (b*b) - 4 * (a*c);
   roots.num_roots = 0;
   if (roots.discriminant >= 0) {
      roots.roots[roots.num_roots++] = (-b + sqrt(roots.discriminant)) / (2 * a);
      if (roots.discriminant > 0)
         roots.roots[roots.num_roots++] = (-b - sqrt(roots.discriminant)) / (2 * a);
      }
   }

   return roots;
}

void printResults(double a, double b, double c, roots_t roots) {
   if (roots.num_roots == 2) {
      printf("The quantity (b^2-4ac) is %.2lf\n", roots.discriminant);
      printf("roots = %.2lf, %.2lf\n", roots.roots[0], roots.roots[1]);
   }
   else if (roots.num_roots == 1) {
      printf("The quantity (b^2-4ac) is %.2lf\n", roots.discriminant);
      printf("roots = %.2lf\n", roots.roots[0]);
   }
   else {
      printf("The discriminant (b^2-4ac) is negative\n");
      printf("roots = <complex>\n");
   }
}

int main(void) {
   double a, b, c;
   getData(&a, &b, &c);
   printResults(a, b, c, calculateRoots(a, b, c));
   return 0;
}
```