# pointer to a struct becomes NULL at every function call

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-value

The problem is that every time the function `addNodePos` is being called `head` pointer is `NULL` (saw that in debugger), and it just creates a list of one node, which points to itself as it is a circular doubly-linked list. And it displays *"List is empty."* because `list` is also `NULL`, when passing to a `printList` function.  Have been trying to understand why but still there is no result.

Here is the code (removed excessive code according to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct DoubleList
{
    int id;
    struct DoubleList *next;
    struct DoubleList *prev;
};

void addNodePos(struct DoubleList* head, int value, int position);
void printList (struct DoubleList* head);
//void clearList (struct DoubleList* head);


int main()
{
    int value, position;
    struct DoubleList *list = NULL;

    printf("\nvalue: ");
    scanf("%x", &value);
    printf("position: ");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    addNodePos(list, value, position);

    printf("\nvalue: ");
    scanf("%x", &value);
    printf("position: ");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    addNodePos(list, value, position);


    printList(list);
    //clearList(list);
    return 0;
}


void addNodePos(struct DoubleList* head, int value, int position)
{
    int i;
    struct DoubleList *node;

    if ( (node = malloc (sizeof(struct DoubleList))) != NULL ){
        node->id=value;
        if (head==NULL) {
            // points to itself as it is the only node in a list
            node->next=node;
            node->prev=node;
            head=node;
        } else {
            struct DoubleList *current=head;
            for (i = position; i > 1; i--)
                current=current->next;
            // reassign pointers -- relink nodes
            current->prev->next=node;
            node->prev=current->prev;
            node->next=current;
            current->prev=node;
        }
    }

    printf("Element has been added.\n\n");
}


void printList(struct DoubleList* head)
{
    if (head==NULL)
        printf("\nList is empty.\n\n");
    else {
        struct DoubleList *current=head;
        printf("\nThe list: ");
        do {
            printf("%d", current->id);
            current=current->next;
            if(current != head)
                printf("<->");
        } while(current!=head);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959694/why-does-call-by-value-example-not-modify-input-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a great help of users (which shared some very useful links), I have managed solving it.

**Solution: to modify caller memory, pass a pointer to that memory.**

After a bit updating, I leave here correctly working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct DoubleList
{
    int id;
    struct DoubleList *next;
    struct DoubleList *prev;
};

void addNodePos(struct DoubleList** headRef, int value, int position);
void printList (struct DoubleList** headRef);
//void clearList (struct DoubleList** headRef);


int main()
{
    int value, position;

    struct DoubleList *list = NULL;

    printf("\nvalue: ");
    scanf("%x", &value);
    printf("position: ");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    addNodePos(&list, value, position);

    printf("\nvalue: ");
    scanf("%x", &value);
    printf("position: ");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    addNodePos(&list, value, position);


    printList(&list);
    //clearList(head);
    return 0;
}




void addNodePos(struct DoubleList** headRef, int value, int position)
{
    int i;
    struct DoubleList *node;

    if ( (node = malloc (sizeof(struct DoubleList))) != NULL ){
        node->id=value;
        if ( (*headRef)==NULL) {
            // points to itself
            node->next=node;
            node->prev=node;
            (*headRef)=node;
        } else {
            struct DoubleList *current=(*headRef);
            for (i = position; i > 1; i--)
                current=current->next;
            // reassign pointers -- relink nodes
            current->prev->next=node;
            node->prev=current->prev;
            node->next=current;
            current->prev=node;
        }
    }
    printf("Element has been added.\n\n");
}



void printList(struct DoubleList** headRef)
{
    if ( (*headRef)==NULL)
        printf("\nList is empty.\n\n");
    else {
        struct DoubleList *current=(*headRef);
        printf("\nThe list: ");
        do {
            printf("%x", current->id);
            current=current->next;
            if(current != (*headRef))
                printf("<->");
        } while(current!=(*headRef));
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could write `&list` rather than having `head`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, good mention) In this way the code will look a bit more clear. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

The address of head is passed by value, so your changes are only reflected in the function itself. You have to pass a pointer to the address of head so that you can change the value.

```
int main() { 
   ...
   addNodePos(&list, value, position);
   ...
}

void addNodePos(struct DoubleList** headPtr, int value, int position)
{
    struct DoubleList *head = *headPtr;
    int i;
    struct DoubleList *node;

    if ( (node = malloc (sizeof(struct DoubleList))) != NULL ){
        node->id=value;
        if (head==NULL) {
            // points to itself as it is the only node in a list
            node->next=node;
            node->prev=node;
            head=node;
        } else {
            struct DoubleList *current=head;
            for (i = position; i > 1; i--)
                current=current->next;
            // reassign pointers -- relink nodes
            current->prev->next=node;
            node->prev=current->prev;
            node->next=current;
            current->prev=node;
        }
    }

    printf("Element has been added.\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are making the same mistake.

Comment: You never update `*headPtr` again once you have modified `head`