# How to iterate through maps with value as pair?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, multimap

I have to implement MST. I wanted to add values as pair. My question is how to iterate through maps with value as pair and how to access the map.

```
    void addedge(multimap<int, pair<int, int> > dirgraph, int source, int dest, int weight)     // graph, source, dest, weight
    {
         dirgraph.insert(make_pair(weight, make_pair(source, dest)));
    }

    multimap<int, pair<int,int> > dirgraph;
    addedge(dirgraph, 0, 1, 5);
    addedge(dirgraph, 0, 4, 3);
    addedge(dirgraph, 1, 2, 1);
    addedge(dirgraph, 1, 4, 4);
    addedge(dirgraph, 4, 3, 3);
    addedge(dirgraph, 2, 3, 2);

    multimap<int, pair<int, int> >::iterator it = dirgraph.begin();
    multimap<int, pair<int, int> >::iterator itend = dirgraph.end();

    for (; it != itend; it++)
           cout << (*it).first << " from " << (*it).second.first << " to " << (*it).second.second << endl; // This dosen't work.
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? And what does that even mean? Please post the error message and maybe even a [mcve].

Comment: For God's sake use `typedef` (or `using`)

Comment: When you pass parameter by value function modifies local copy. Read a textbook.

Comment: Also, if you have C++11 you can loop with `for (auto &i : dirgraph) { ... }` instead of manually using iterators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959694/why-does-call-by-value-example-not-modify-input-parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question was not tagged otherwise, I assume C++11. Here is an annotated and improved version of your code.

```
using edge = std::pair<int,int>;                    // for clarity
using directional_graph = std::multimap<int,edge>;  // not std::map<edge,weight> ?

void add_edge(directional_graph &dirgraph,          // pass by reference
              int source, int dest, int weight)
{
  dirgraph.insert(std::make_pair(weight, std::make_pair(source, dest)));
}

directional_graph dirgraph;
add_edge(dirgraph, 0, 1, 5);
add_edge(dirgraph, 0, 4, 3);
add_edge(dirgraph, 1, 2, 1);
add_edge(dirgraph, 1, 4, 4);
add_edge(dirgraph, 4, 3, 3);
add_edge(dirgraph, 2, 3, 2);

for(const auto&x : dirgraph)
  std::cout << x.first << " from " << x.second.first << " to "
            << x.second.second << std::endl;
```

Note that this code is much clearer and cleaner. I used `std::` to avoid the bad `using namespace std;`. Most importantly, this code is correct in the sense that `add_edge()` actually changes the first argument. In your code, you created a local copy of the graph, which was modified without any effect on the actual graph.

Just a side note: I find is strange that you use the weights of a graph as the keys: do you really want to identify the edges by their weights? I would have thought that the `edge` type is more suitable as key. In this case and if edges are unique, then you don't need a `multimap`, but only an ordinary `map`.